# How can I populate nested documents in Typegoose?

Tags: mongoose, typegoose

Let's say I have 3 schemas.

```js
class User {
    @Prop()
    name: string
}

class Exam {
    @Prop()
    name: string

    @Prop({ ref: () => Exam }, PropType.ARRAY)
    examReq?: Ref<Exam>[]
}

class UserExam {
    @Prop({ ref: () => User })
    userId: Ref<User>

    @Prop({ ref: () => Exam })
    examId: Ref<Exam>
}
```

How can I populate all these nested documents while doing a find? I tried the following and the exam is getting populated but examReq is returning empty.

```
userExamModel.find({ _id: id }).populate('examId').populate('examId.examReq')
```

Comment: are there any errors? also is the `examReq` array actually filled with valid `ObjectId`'s? also maybe try to use `mongoose.set('debug', true)` and see what queries get executed (set this before your `.find` line)

Comment: No errors and yes examReq has valid ObjectId

Comment: ```mongoose.set('debug', true)``` returns ```Mongoose: userexams.find({ userId: new ObjectId("63838b58b0a823d0080a9617") }, { projection: {} })```
```Mongoose: exams.find({ _id: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("6386370d9e84185be06422f7") ], [Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: {}})```

Answer (score 0):

(This Question was also asked in the typegoose issues as [#773](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/773) and was answered by `@teynar`)

If there are multiple `.populate` calls with the same path before being run, then only the last `.populate` call will take effect, as documented in [Mongoose: Populating Multiple Paths](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths).

A workaround for this case would be:

```js
.populate({ path: 'examId', populate: { path: 'examReq' } });
// Note that just "examId.examReq" does not work
```

Which results in 2(3 if you count `find` itself) different queries anyway, so it would be the same as doing:

```js
const doc = await Model.findOne({});
await doc.populate('examId');
await doc.populate('examReq');
```